# Training model to recognize one specific object (or scene)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am trying to train a learning model to recognize one specific scene. For example, say I would like to train it to recognize pictures taken at an amusement park and I already have 10 thousand pictures taken at an amusement park. I would like to train this model with those pictures so that it would be able to give a score for other pictures of the probability that they were taken at an amusement park. How do I do that?
Considering this is an image recognition problem, I would probably use a convolutional neural network, but I am not quite sure how to train it in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways. The most trivial one is to collect a large number of negative examples (images from other places) and train a two-class model.

The second approach would be to train a network to extract meaningful low-dimensional representations from an input image (embeddings). Here you can use siamese training to explicitly train the network to learn similarities between images. Such an approach is employed for face recognition, for instance (see [FaceNet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet)). Having such embeddings, you can use some well-established methods for outlier detections, for instance, 1-class SVM, or any other classifier. In this case you also need negative examples.

I would heavily augment your data using image cropping - it is the most obvious way to increase the amount of training data in your case.

In general, your success in this task strongly depends on the task statement (are restricted to parks only, or any kind of place) and the proper data.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually never heard of siamese training so will definitely look into that. Just one more question. Is there any way of doing this without negative examples at all? Thanks again.

Comment: Training on positive examples only is possible for other models, but I am not aware of it for neural networks. And it's definitely impossible for siamese approach. But collecting negative examples would be the simplest solution compared to constructing exotic training frameworks for positive examples only.